# Could anybody give me an example of finite measure which has non-zero value for all non-empty measurable set?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to construct a finite measure defined on Borel sigma algebra of $[0,1]$ such that every nonempty set has nonzero measure.

Can anybody give me a help to find out such measure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your title says "non-negative", your question says "nonzero".  Which did you mean?

Comment: Non-zero. I edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Such a measure doesn't exist.

Assume that $\mu([0, 1]) = M < \infty$. Then the cardinality of $T_n = \{x \in [0, 1] \mid \mu(\{x\}) > \frac{1}{n}\}$ is at most $Mn$ and therefore finite. Since every nonempty set is supposed to have a positive measure, the identity $[0, 1] = \bigcup \limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} T_n$ holds. But this is impossible, since $[0, 1]$ is uncountable and the countable union of finite sets is at most countable.

Comment: It even follows, that such a measure can't be $\sigma$-finite at all.

Comment: +1, but: Possibly not the best choice to use $M$ as a real number and $M_n$ as sets.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are right, I've changed $M_n$ to $T_n$. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Quite illuminating. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if this should be obvious, but why is it that $|T_n| \leq Mn$?

Comment: @kdbanman If you could pick $Mn + 1$ elements out of the set, their union would have a mass of at least $(Mn + 1)/n = M + 1/n > M$, which contraditcs $\mu([0, 1]) = M$.