# What is the name for the distribution of values taken by a stochastic process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, terminology

Say we have a stochastic process $ \{X_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{I}}$ with index set $\mathbb{I}$ where each random variable $X_t$ has the same measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ as its domain.  That is,

$$
X_t: (\Omega, \mathcal{F}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})
$$

where $X_t$ can be arbitrary measurable functions.

### Question

Is it meaningful to ask for the distribution of values in $\mathbb{R}$ taken by process $\{X_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{I}}$?

(And does that distribution have a name?)

### Example

Let index set $\mathbb{I} = [0, 1]$, and process $\{X_t\}_{t \in [0, 1]}$ be defined as

$$
X_t \sim \sin(2 \pi t) + \text{Uniform}[-1, 1]
$$

Then trajectories $f(t)$ are simply a single period of the $\sin(t)$ curve, translated vertically by a random amount.

> [image: Sample path.]

Following graphical intuition *only,* the distribution of values taken by trajectories $f \sim \{X_t\}$ is simply an integral over time:

$$
\begin{align}
p(x) & = \int_\mathbb{I} p_X(x, t) dt \\
     & = \int_{[0, 1]} p_X(x, t) dt
\end{align}
$$

> [image: "Marginal over time" example.]

This looks suspiciously like a marginal distribution over time, hence the following line of reasoning.

### Generalization

Under certain conditions, my question is essentially asking for the "marginal over time."  Quotation marks are used, because that idea feels a little off.  If it's not clear why, hopefully it will be soon:

1. **Pushforwards.**

   One can ask for the distribution of values taken by a
   *single* random variable $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  It's just the pushforward $\mu X^{-1}$ from measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$.
2. **Measurable Trajectories.**

   Our stochastic process $ \{X_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{I}}$ produces
   trajectories that are functions of the index set.  i.e. $f \sim X_t
   \implies f:\mathbb{I} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  If those functions
   $f$ are measurable on $(\mathbb{I}, \mathcal{I})$, where
   $\mathcal{I}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{I}$, then each $f$
   is itself a random variable.
3. **Pushforwards from trajectories.**

   Let $p$ be a distribution on our index set $\mathbb{I}$ so that we
   have measure space $(\mathbb{I}, \mathcal{I}, p)$.  Then each
   $f:\mathbb{I} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ will induce a distribution $p
   f^{-1}$ over $\mathbb{R}$, just like in observation 1.  It feels strange to assign a distribution to the index set.  But let's hand wave: since we know each index will be encountered precisely once over the course of a sample of $X_t$, let $p$ be the uniform distribution over $\mathbb{I}$.  This imposes [constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1431333/426612) on the index set.
4. **Marginal over time.**

   The process $ \{X_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{I}}$ induces a distribution over the set of trajectories, and each trajectory $f$ induces a distribution $p f^{-1}$ over $\mathbb{R}$, so we have a distribution of distributions over $\mathbb{R}$.     I am asking if/when it's meaningful to ask for the "total" distribution induced in the values $x \in \mathbb{R}$ taken by trajectories $f: \mathbb{I} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. And under the constraints and hand waving above, this is simply the marginal over time $p(\omega) = \int_\mathbb{I} p_X(\omega, t) dt$

### Issues

The ideas above leading to "marginals over time" doesn't feel correct for two reasons.

- I don't see why the "total" distribution should depend upon measurability of trajectories.

  For instance, consider the process  $\{V_t\}_{t \in [0, 1]}$ where

  $$
     V_t = \text{Uniform} \left[ \sin(2 \pi t) - 1, \sin(2 \pi t) + 1 \right]
     $$

  The distribution of values taken by $\{V_t\}$ is the same as the example process $\{X_t\}$.  However, ${V_t}$ doesn't have measurable trajectories $g(t) \sim V_t$ by a similar argument to example 3.10 [here](http://stat.math.uregina.ca/%7Ekozdron/Teaching/Regina/862Winter06/Handouts/revised_lecture1.pdf), so integrating to get a marginal is impossible.
- I'm intuitively convinced that the distribution of values taken by $\{X_t\}$ can exist even when the index set $\mathbb{I}$ is unbounded and uncountable, which the "marginal over time" technique does not permit.

  For instance, consider the same process $X_t$ as the example, but with $\mathbb{I} = \mathbb{R}$ instead of $[0, 1]$.  The trajectories are periodic, so appending another period will have no effect on the distribution of values taken by $\{X_t\}$, and appending more periods ad infinitum should induce the same distribution of values taken by the process, no?  But there does not exist a uniform measure supported by $\mathbb{R}$ (or any other unbounded uncountable set), and without a measure there is no integral, and hence no marginal over indices $\mathbb{I}$.